# Safe-global/auth-kit import in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, npm-package, gnosis-safe

Is it possible to import & use @safe-global/auth-kit npm package in vanilla JS environment using unpkg?

Tried multiple ways to import & use auth-kit npm package in vanilla JS environment.